# A property of almost Riemannian submersions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Definition.** A smooth map $f\colon M\to N$ of two smooth Riemannian manifolds is called $\varepsilon$-almost Riemannian submersion (here $0\leq \varepsilon<1/100$) if for any point $x\in M$ and any tangent vector $\xi\in T_xM$ which is orthogonal to the fiber $f^{-1}(f(x))$ one has $$(1-\varepsilon) ||df(\xi)||\leq ||\xi||\leq (1+\varepsilon)||df(\xi)||.$$

**Question.** Given an $\varepsilon$-Riemannian proper submersion as above. Does there exist $\delta >0$ with the following property? Given any point $y\in N$ and a shortest path $\gamma\colon [a,b]\to M$ whose endpoints belong to the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$. Assume that this path is $\varepsilon$-almost orthogonal to the former fiber at its initial point $a$, i.e. the angle $\alpha$ between  $\gamma'(a)$ and the tangent space to the fiber satisfies $|\alpha-\pi/2|<\varepsilon.$ **Then the image $f(\gamma)$ of the path cannot be  contained in the $\delta$-neighborhood of the point $y$.**

For my applications $\delta$ might depend on $\varepsilon$, any geometry of $N$, and a lower bound on sectional curvature of $M$ (but not on other geometric properties of $M$).

**Remarks.** (1) For $\varepsilon=0$ the answer is known to be positive, and $\delta$ can be taken less then the injectivity radius of $N$.

(2) In my case $M$ might have a convex boundary (while $N$ has no boundary) and the restriction of $f$ to $\partial M$ is also assumed to be an $\varepsilon$-almost Riemannian submersion.